# Windows clients not able to join to a domain hosted by qnap nas

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller, network-attached-storage, qnap

I am pretty new in networking and I bumped into a challenge that I am not able to solve for three days. What I would like to achieve is to join a windows server (windows server 2016) and Windows 10 clients to an active directory domain hosted by a qnap NAS (TVS-473e).

I tried to follow the available tutorials and read all the available documentation by qnap. here for example pretty well describe what I want: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Joining_a_Windows_Client_or_Server_to_a_Domain

What I managed to do :

I enabled the domain controller - have the domain name set-up with "domain_name".local format in qnap nas

I have domain users and groups and able to authenticate and see the shared folders with their respected user rights (from qnap applications)

In the DNS setting I see my domain three with the "domain_name".local as well as the _msdcs."domain_name".local

On the windows server 2016 - I have set up a fixed IP and for the DNS server I have set up the preferred as 127.0.1.1 and as alternate 8.8.8.8 (this is the same which is set up for the NAS in the network / virtual switch set-up.

however, when I try to add the windows clients to a domain by the GUI or either in power shell, I got the following error:

The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain ""domain_name"".local":

I see that there is something with the DNS as in the nslookup my domain name is cannot be resolved in the local network however I have no idea how I could overcome this. I really appreciate some guides here. Thanks in advance

Tamas

Comment: I don't see anything on the specification sheet about the appliance "hosting" Active Directory.

Comment: Hi @GregAskew, what specification sheet are you referring to?

Comment: https://www.qnap.com/en-us/product/tvs-473e/specs/software

Comment: Point your clients DNS to your DNS hosting your zones instead of google ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enable the Domain Controller component on the QNAP it also enables the DNS Server component. The DNS Server component is the DNS server for the Domain and hosts the domain DNS zones.

On the server that you want to join to the domain you need to set the DNS server to the ip address of the QNAP.

Comment: Thanks a lot @joeqwerty. It is very logical and works! Only additional thing was to provide the needed rights at the client for the domain admin commands to samba